# EF 4.0 get EntitySetMappings from MetadataWorkspace

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I am using EF 4.0, and I am trying to query all the items from the mapping dataspace.

Using the following code,

```
var item = this.MetadataWorkspace.GetItems<EdmType>(DataSpace.CSSpace);
```

I get an error

'The space 'CSSpace' has no associated collection'

Eventually i am trying to query EntitySetMappings from the edmx file so i can know which EntityTypes are mapped to a particular EntitySet...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to force load the SSpace.

```
string sql = ((System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery)this.[AnyEntitySet]).ToTraceString();
```

For more information take a look at [Forcing MetadataWorkspace ItemCollections to load](http://thedatafarm.com/blog/data-access/quick-trick-for-forcing-metadataworkspace-itemcollections-to-load/).